# updating my application through my website

Tags: c#

supposing i would add some new features to my desktop application (including developing a new winwindow in my application and attaching new files), and i would upload this new updated application to my website, how is it possible to let users update their version with my latest version, as several programs do, without having to uninstall the current version and re-install the latest version? For example Google Chrome can automatically update its user interface and options without Un-installation and re-installation!

Comment: https://github.com/github/Shimmer

Comment: sorry but isn' that what Clickonce is all about? why don't you use that?

Comment: Be careful with ClickOnce. It does not play nicely with corporate firewalls, so if you clients are accessing your app over the internet rather than an intranet, you might end up with a lot of support issues from clients who cannot install/update the app. (I'm speaking from painful experience here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either:

- just open a web page when a new version is released (slightly annoying)
- use a technology like Clickonce or Java's equivalent to handle the updates for you
- choose an Installer which handles updates for you, like Installshield
- code your own (harder)